# Cron.weekly is not running on Sunday as per the crontab default

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

We have few scripts to clean up the sftp server that we are placed in cron.weekly folder to run on Sunday @6:47 as per crontab defaults, but they are running g on Monday @ 07:40 instead!! and this is causing  a big problem due to retention policy on sftp server? I tried to find if anything has been changed and I can tell we are not. we running ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Output of `cat /etc/crontab`?

Comment: also check logs at /var/log/cron